# PostgreSQL how to add an extra column to resulting data table with multiple joins

Tags: postgresql

I'm working to extend a PSQL query to include a new result column which should be called `first_contact`.

There are 3 tables involved and you can check below my DB fiddle for the details:

- candidates
- activities
- statuses

The original query as per the DB fiddle link:

[Updated DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=033ef43aef9b5d352c8113a3eb259967)

What I was trying without success:

[Failing DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=15e58f704ba562b715ef8f08579c26cc)

The new column `first_contact` has to contain the minimum timestamp which is the result between the column `statusFrom` and `statusTo` with a left join to the table `activities` on the column `created_at`.

The goal is to show what was the first contact timestamp of a candidate. That information is stored in activities and the types we are considering are: PHONE, SMS, EMAIL

The resulting data after the extension of the original query should be an example

| id | studyId | siteId | statusType | statusFrom | statusTo | first_contact | first_contact_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EML1 | EML1 | INCOMPLETE | 2022-03-11 08:38:21.986276+00 | 2022-03-13 08:38:45.336072+00 | 2022-03-12 00:00 | SMS |
| 1 | EML1 | EML1 | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 2022-03-13 08:38:45.336072+00 | Null | Null | Null |

In the example, the candidate with ID 1 had 2 status entries.
he or she was between status INCOMPLETE and PENDING_CALLCENTER from date to date as per the table.
The `first_contact` example occurred the `2022-03-12` which cannot be less than `statusFrom` or more than `statusTo`.
Also this candidate was contacted the first time by `SMS`.

The second row has no `statusTo` so we add null on the last columns.

We add also null if we have the situation that there is no resulting `first_contact`.
It is possible a candidate has moved a status without being contacted.

I got blocked as cannot understand how to integrate this new column to the first shared query. I did some tries but got errors.

**UPDATE**
The DB fiddle was updated with a new version showing my try with the first_contact column but is bad results.

What I need as example we have

```
status from > first contact < status to
```

That means we have to find in the activities table the minimum timestamp which is in between the statusFrom and statusTo which is the first contact date/time we need.

a candidate can stay in several statuses for a period of time and we need to know for metrics purposes what was the first time that candidate was contacted in that range of time.

Comment: I think that if you reduced the no. of records in your fiddle, it might help. The size of the fiddle is a bit daunting - maybe fewer records with a couple of more examples might be better?

Comment: I'll try to add fewer data however the example I added in my question to the existing data table resulting from that query, I should add an extra column called first_contact which is the min timestamp from the table activities.
That timestamp needs to be in the range of the columns status from and statusTo 
That data is already present what I cannot figure out how to do the left join to add that timestamp I need from activities based on the range I explained above